# How to implement BDP Bloomberg excel formula to Java blpapi?

Tags: java, bloomberg, blpapi

There is an existing Bloomberg excel formula that I need to implement using Java Bloomberg API.
The existing excel formula is like this.

> BDP(Ticker, Field, FiscalPeriod, PeriodEnd, Compound, filing_status)

An example of the parameters are shown below.

```
Ticker: FMD US Equity 
Field: ARD_ST_INVEST 
Fiscal Period: Q4 
PeriodEnd: 2007-06-30 
Compound: CONSOLIDATED 
filing_status: MR
```

This formula retrieves the ARD_ST_INVEST's value for FMD US Equity and saves it to a cell in the excel file.

So far, what I only know and what have been doing in blpapi(Java) is to create a HistoricalDataRequest just like below,

```
Service refDataSvc = session.getService("//blp/refdata");
Request request = refDataSvc.createRequest("HistoricalDataRequest");
request.set("adjustmentFollowDPDF", false);
request.set("adjustmentNormal", false);
```

Now, I am not sure how to code the BDP formula in blpapi(Java).
From what I've read in blpapi's developer's guide, there are quite a few operations available under Reference Data Service //blp/refdata.
(i.e. HistoricalDataRequest, IntraDayTickRequest, ReferenceDataRequest, etc.)

Upon some reading BDP is explained as,

> BDP (Bloomberg Data Point) is for static or real time current data.
>     It returns data to a single cell in your Excel spreadsheet.

But still, I do not know how I should translate the Bloomberg excel formula above to Java blpapi.
Should I create a HistoricalDataRequest or a ReferenceDataRequest, etc.?
How should I set the FiscalPeriod, PeriodEnd, Filing_status, Ticker, Field, etc.?

Comment: It would be a reference data request and you can add overrides with something like `Element overridesElt = request.getElement("overrides"); Element override = overridesElt.appendElement(); override.setElement("fieldId", "FiscalPeriod"); override.setElement("value", "Q4");`. Alternatively, if you can use external libraries, you may want to have a look a jbloomberg (disclaimer: I am the author) - your problem could be solved in 5 or 6 lines of code.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll take a look at jbloomberg. Thank you!

Comment: There are a few examples at the bottom of [this page](http://assylias.github.io/jBloomberg/apidocs/index.html)

Comment: Thank you @assylias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is the comment @assylias posted on the question itself.